# How to shoehorn AND/OR logic into an existing INDEX and AGGREGATE function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate, countif

I have an Excel-based questionnaire, where the user chooses Low, Med, or High risk per question from a validated dropdown list, and multiple columns to the right will populate based on the answer selected. Per row, the columns look like this:

[Question] [Risk selection (L/M/H)] [Next steps] [cross references] [etc.]

I'm trying to generate a summary report, where all the Med AND High answers and their next steps/cross references/etc. are grouped together in a single list on another worksheet, with the same column layout, without blanks. I found this fantastic solution for building an intelligent list based on a single response (e.g. Med OR High): https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/ (Method #1)

Based on that walkthrough, I have the following formula:

`=IF(ROWS($I$5:I5)<=$I$4,INDEX(TableDiv[DD Q ID:],AGGREGATE(15,3,(TableDiv[Risk Level]=$J$4)/(TableDiv[Risk Level]=$J$4)*(ROW(TableDiv[Risk Level])-ROW(TableDiv[Risk Level])),ROWS($I$5:I5))),"")`

Where I4 contains `=COUNTIF(TableDiv[Risk Level],$J$4)` (e.g. the count of Med or High responses in the Risk selection column, as defined by the "Med" or "High" value entered in J4).

It works great, but I can't figure out how to make the formula count both Med AND High selections, instead of just Med or just High. I've tried defining I4 as both Med and High, summing two COUNTIF functions in I4 (e.g. `=SUM(COUNTIF(TableDiv[Risk Level],"Med")+(COUNTIF(TableDiv[Risk Level],"High")`), and played with COUNTIFS, but so far all efforts break the formula. Even when it kind of works, extending the formula to other columns returns different rows (i.e. the returned values under [Next steps] and [cross references] no longer match the [Question] for that row). It feels like there has to be an easy way to say "Count IF Med OR High", or "Count Med AND High", but I'm stuck.

Any ideas? A solution that assigns a number value to L/M/H and does a "Count if >="Med" " would also work, just not sure how to do that. Max 50 rows, and using Office365, so fancy new functions are fine.

Sample data:

```
Question 1 | Low | No action needed. | ID-1 | notes...

Question 2 | Med | Some extra steps. | ID-4 | considerations...

Question 3 | Low | No action needed. | ID-5 | comments...

Question 4 | High| Lots of steps.    | ID-9 | more notes...

Question 5 | Med | Some extra steps. | ID-12| add'l notes...
```

vs.

Expected output (Med & High, no blanks, in a different worksheet):

```
Question 2 | Med | Some extra steps. | ID-4 | considerations...

Question 4 | High| Lots of steps.    | ID-9 | more notes...

Question 5 | Med | Some extra steps. | ID-12| add'l notes...
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help to put some context to the equations.

Comment: Sample data and expected output added.